# How do I make the sound from raspberry pi go to iPod Touch

Tags: raspberry-pi, ipod

I am making a raspberry pi robot and I wanted to know if there was a way to connect an IPod Touch(1st gen) to the rpi via USB port,then use the IPod as a speaker for my rpi?

Comment: why ipod and not conventional speakers?

Comment: It would be cooler,and I can use the other hardware on the IPod for different rpi uses